# Structuring documentation with sphinx autodoc

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc

So, I have two modules:

```
"""
Module 1
=========
"""
def foo():
    """foo doc"""
```

and

```
"""
Module 2
=========
"""
def bar():
    """bar doc"""
```

Then I have a rst file that goes like

```
*************
Some heading
*************

.. automodule:: package.module1
    :members:

.. automodule:: package.module2
    :members:
```

The build gives me a side bar structure like this:

```
[+] Some Heading
    Module 1
    foo        
    Module 2
    bar
```

Obviously, the headings from the module doc strings are on the same level as the members of the same module. I don't like this.

Instead I found, that moving the headings from the module doc strings to the rst file like

```
*************
Some heading
*************

Module 1
=========

.. automodule:: package.module1
    :members:

Module 2
=========

.. automodule:: package.module2
    :members:
```

gives me the structure that I expected, which is:

```
[+] Some Heading
    [+] Module 1
        foo 
    [+] Module 2
        func1
        bar
```

How can I get autodoc (or sphinx?) to turn headings in module doc strings to expandable sections in the side bar?

Answer (score 0):

I actually also try to build html documentations from my doc- strings by using sphinx. My perceptions are the following:

```
This will produce an own entry on the left on a top level
============================================================

============================================================
headline will be first sub-level
============================================================


############################################################
parts will be second sub- level
############################################################

************************************************************
chapter will be the third sub- level
************************************************************

another entry on top level
============================================================
```

that will be shown in the following way

```
[x] DOCUMENT1 (containing all the lines above)
[x] This will produce an own entry on the left on a top level
    [+] headline will be first sub-level
        [+] parts will be second sub- level
            [+] chapter will be the third sub- level
[x] another entry on top level
```

HTH